# How do you make a column of text slanted without spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I make a column of text in HTML appear like this without using spaces?

Is this possible with CSS only? I feel like this is going to be in jQuery territory.

[image]

```css
.column{
  Width:300px;
  height:auto;
  background-color:#999;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
<p>

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna</p> <p>aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><p>

 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been searching for similar questions, haven't been able to find any. I'm not a CSS pro, but I suspect some kind of transform property is needed.

Comment: @Barmar can use `shape-outside` property for generating shape.

Comment: Try this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_shapes_parallel

Answer (score 2):

can achieve with CSS `shape-outside` property. this will wrap content around shape like circle, ellipse or polygon.

in case of  `Triangle Bottom Left` kind of shape, can use `polygon`

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside

```css
.column {
  width:50%;
  background-color:#999;
}
    
 .shape {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30em;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
<div class="shape"></div>
<p>

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna</p> <p>aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><p>

 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

NOTE: IE *No support*

Comment: Just note that `shape-outside` won't work in IE and Edge https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside

Comment: @sallf yes... Thanks added NOTE to answer

Comment: Note that if the text is longer than the height of the polygon, the rest of it will not be angled.

Comment: To bad it won't work in edge, would be excellent otherwise :(

Comment: @Barmar can use % values instead. updated Answer accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: That seems to work. But if it eventually reaches the right edge, it stops angling and the rest is full width. Try doubling or tripling the text to see this effect.

Comment: @Barmar then only solution is to increase the height of `.shape`